# NSStatusItem custom view NSDraggingDestination only works after click of item

Tags: cocoa, swift

I have an NSStatusItem with a custom view that implements the NSDraggingDestination protocol. However, dragging and dropping only works if the status item was clicked / activated at least once. I want the custom view to accept drops regardless.

A gif to showcase the problem:
[image: Gif.]

Code from the example above (or [Xcode Project](http://cl.ly/Wl1j/MenuTest.zip)):

```
import Cocoa
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification?) {
        let vc = StatusItemViewController()
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(aNotification: NSNotification?) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }

}

class StatusItemView: NSView, NSDraggingDestination {
    public var image = NSImage(named: "NSQuickLookTemplate")
    public var action: Selector?
    public var target: AnyObject?

    private var statusItem: NSStatusItem

    init(statusItem: NSStatusItem) {
        let itemWidth = statusItem.length
        let itemHeight = NSStatusBar.systemStatusBar().thickness
        self.statusItem = statusItem
        super.init(frame: NSRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: itemWidth, height: itemHeight))

        var types = [NSURLPboardType, NSStringPboardType] as [String]
        for type in NSImage.imagePasteboardTypes() {
            types.append(type as String)
        }
        self.registerForDraggedTypes(types)
        statusItem.view = self
    }

    override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        let iconSize = image.size
        let bounds = self.bounds
        let iconX = round((bounds.width - iconSize.width)/2)
        let iconY = round((bounds.height - iconSize.height)/2)
        image.drawAtPoint(NSPoint(x: iconX, y: iconY), fromRect: NSRect(), operation: NSCompositingOperation.CompositeOverlay, fraction: 1.0)
    }

    override func mouseDown(theEvent: NSEvent!) {
        if let _action = self.action {
            NSApp.sendAction(_action, to: self.target, from: self)
        }
    }

    override func performDragOperation(sender: NSDraggingInfo!) -> Bool {
        println("Performed")
        return true
    }

    override func draggingEntered(sender: NSDraggingInfo!) -> NSDragOperation {
        return NSDragOperation.Copy
    }

    override func draggingUpdated(sender: NSDraggingInfo!) -> NSDragOperation {
        println("Dragging")
        return NSDragOperation.Copy
    }

    override func draggingExited(sender: NSDraggingInfo!) {
        println("Exit")
    }
}

class StatusItemViewController: NSObject {
    private var statusBarItem: NSStatusItem?
    private var statusItemView: StatusItemView!

    init() {
        self.statusBarItem = NSStatusBar.systemStatusBar().statusItemWithLength(24)
        super.init()
        if let item = statusBarItem {
            statusItemView = StatusItemView(statusItem: item)
            statusItemView.target = self
            statusItemView.action = "doAction:"
        } else {
            println("Unable to create status item, terminating self")
            NSApplication.sharedApplication().terminate(nil)
        }
    }

    deinit {
        NSStatusBar.systemStatusBar().removeStatusItem(statusBarItem)
        statusBarItem = nil
        statusItemView = nil
    }

    func doAction(sender: AnyObject!) {
        println("Here is where one would perform the action")
    }
}
```

Perhaps this is a bug or perhaps I'm just missing something. Why is this happening and is there anything I can do to prevent this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it was a bug. I have just tested your project using XCode 6.1.1 and OS X 10.10.2 and drugging works just fine.